# Python Check for a Draw in Connect 4

Tags: python

I'm trying to code a game of Connect 4 in Python right now - where the board is 6 rows and 7 columns, and I'm facing difficulty with checking whether a draw has occurred. A draw will happen when all elements in the board are occupied by either a 1 or 2.

```
curr_board = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
              [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
              [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
              [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]
for row in curr_board:
    if curr_board and all(piece == 1 or piece == 2 for piece in row):
        print("draw")
```

This returns:

```
draw
draw
draw
draw
draw
draw
```

I understand that what is happening is it checks row 1, returns draw, checks row 2, returns draw etc. How do I make it check all the rows first before returning draw?

**EDIT:**

```
counter = 0
for row in curr_board:
    if curr_board and all(piece == 1 or piece == 2 for piece in row):
        counter += 1
if counter == 6:
    print("draw")
```

I have solved the problem by doing this, however - is there a more elegant way to solve this?

Comment: Why not just check the top row? Is it not the standard Connect 4?

Comment: Btw what value(s) other than 1 and 2 might be in the board?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to check for wins and draws, it is a little bit of a bulkier solution, but is an all in one function. You would just have to copy it and rename "tile = '1'" and "check1Win"

```
curr_board = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
]


def check1Win(board):

    boardHeight = len(board)
    boardWidth = len(board[0])
    tile = "1"
    # check horizontal spaces
    for y in range(boardHeight):
        for x in range(boardWidth - 3):
            if (
                board[x][y] == tile
                and board[x + 1][y] == tile
                and board[x + 2][y] == tile
                and board[x + 3][y] == tile
            ):
                return True

    # check vertical spaces
    for x in range(boardWidth):
        for y in range(boardHeight - 3):
            if (
                board[x][y] == tile
                and board[x][y + 1] == tile
                and board[x][y + 2] == tile
                and board[x][y + 3] == tile
            ):
                return True

    # check / diagonal spaces
    for x in range(boardWidth - 3):
        for y in range(3, boardHeight):
            if (
                board[x][y] == tile
                and board[x + 1][y - 1] == tile
                and board[x + 2][y - 2] == tile
                and board[x + 3][y - 3] == tile
            ):
                return True

    # check \ diagonal spaces
    for x in range(boardWidth - 3):
        for y in range(boardHeight - 3):
            if (
                board[x][y] == tile
                and board[x + 1][y + 1] == tile
                and board[x + 2][y + 2] == tile
                and board[x + 3][y + 3] == tile
            ):
                return True

    return "Draw"


print(checkOWin(curr_board))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```py
import itertools

if all(piece == 1 or piece == 2 for piece in itertools.chain.from_iterable(curr_board)):
    print("draw")
```

And this works too, I like it better:

```py
import itertools

set_board = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(curr_board))
if set_board.issubset({1, 2}):
    print("draw")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if all(piece in (1, 2) for row in curr_board for piece in row):
   print('draw')
```

Comment: Please keep in mind this is close to unreadable, and should not be used as a viable solution in production.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand the question, but if you want to figure out whether all of the horizontal pieces are 1, 2, or a combination, then the following will work. Sorry if I misunderstood.

```
board = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]

for row in board:
    myset = set(row)
    if len(myset) > 1:
        print("draw")
    if myset == {2}:
        print("2 wins")
    if myset == {1}:
        print("1 wins")
```

This outputs:

```
1 wins
1 wins
draw
2 wins
draw
2 wins
```